# not runing multiple BackgroundServices together in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I implemented three BackgroundServices .The first (x) is executed but the next two (y,z) are not.

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<x>();
            services.AddHostedService<y>();
            services.AddHostedService<z>();
        }
```

The implementation of all three BackgroundServices is as follows:

```
public class x : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {              
                    func1();                                         
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem was solved when I used "try,catch" in the implementations of the BackgroundServices and all three start working together at the same time.

```
public class x : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    func1();
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I do not know why this problem occurred. what's the reason?
Lots of thanks to anyone who will answer me.

Comment: Was an exception caught in your catch block? If so, which one?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to service x running synchronously and never coming back. When using try catch you await Task.Delay which makes your code go asynchronous.

Edit: Thank you Stephen Cleary for the [explanation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html)!

Comment: why service x running syncronously ? Shouldn't several BackgroundServices be executed together normally (Asynchronously)? What is the need for try_catch?  That is, an error occurs in the first background service that causes this problem?

Comment: Async methods are compiled to be a state machines. The code excecutes synchronoulsly until some asynchronous work is performed. What exception is thrown?

Comment: `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {              
                    await func1();                                         
            }`                                                                                                                                       Excuse me, I forgot to put the "await" in the service implementation in question .  Please answer this question by considering.

Comment: There is no error. The only problem is that one of the services is running. A friend of mine says it could be because of in-app dependencies.

Comment: Async methods complete synchronously unless you use Task.Run or await a call that does - normally when I/O is concerned. You can verify this by calling await Task.Run(func1).

Comment: Thank you for your patience in responding

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the Try Catch. `func1` runs synchronously so `x.ExecuteAsync` loop synchronously and never return the handle to `StartAsync` to run `y.ExecuteAsync` and `z.ExecuteAsync`.
When awaiting `Task.Delay` you return the handle to `StartAsync` which can execute y and z.